# How close for the toilet and vanity

Tags: bathroom, toilet, vanity

is there a rule of thumb, for how close the bathroom vanity should be next to the toilet...

Doing a remodel, and would like to have a larger vanity, but don't want to encroach on the toilet and (um) comfortable seating.

And for full disclosure, I had a plumbing issue, the local ServePro guys removed everything in the bathroom - toilet and vanity - so, I could not measure it or "test" it before everything was torn out - let's say it was an emergency...

Thanks

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. I'm no pro, but Googling ["distance from vanity to toilet"](https://www.google.com/search?q=distance+from+vanity+to+toilet) turned up a number of resources.

Comment: Good call - I did and found the answer...good video too - thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped. Would you mind adding your answer to your question, so that future visitors will know? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

30" clear across so 15" from center of the flange to either side is the minimum. There is a little wiggle room like 1/2-1" less on one side if the other side is completely open and you have to consider the size of the occupants.

Comment: The Code does not give “wiggle room”. Where did the wiggle room come from?

Comment: Very true Lee Sam no argument here. It's not uncommon to pass a plumbing inspection with one wall slightly closer than 15"

Comment: Funny thing I haven't had an inspector EVER measure a flange to wall , just saying if it fits it will pass

Comment: Up here in the Great White North inspectors often check. Guys hate how thorough they are. I love it. It gets rid of the fly by nighters.

Answer (score 2):

I place my flanges 13” from center flange to back wall but code says 12” from back wall to center of flange.  side to side code say 30” from side to side, or 15” on center. Make sure you take into account the 1/2” overhang of the countertop/sink top, I’ve had an inspector fail me because of the sink top hanging a 1/2” over the vanity so it made my flange 14 and a half inches center. We pulled the sink top and just made It flush with vanity on that one side.  If you are going for ADA code says 36” from side to side or 18”’center.